# Django feed framework: tzinfo error

Tags: django, datetime, feed

I am using django feed framework. This is what I have in my feeds.py:

```
def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return item.posted
```

This is what I have in my Blog class in models.py:

```
posted = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

And I get this attribute error:

```
'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/ for the requirements of `def item_pubdate`. This is because most feed formats technically require a full timestamp as the publish date.

The function you define `item_pubdate` for a feed must return a python `datetime.datetime` object, not a `datetime.date` object. The difference being of course that the object can contain a specific time in addition to the date information.

Therefore, you must use `models.DateTimeField` instead of `models.DateField`.

--

If you are stuck using the `models.DateField`, then you can have your feed class do the conversion:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return datetime.combine(item.posted, time())
```

And that should get your date converted to a datetime so that contrib.syndication accepts it.

Comment: I already have lots of data in the database, so it would be risky to change the models. Are there any work arounds?

Comment: Just added a workaround to the above answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Django is expecting a `datetime` instead of a `date`. Here's a way to covert it:

```
import datetime

def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return datetime.datetime(item.posted.year, item.posted.month, item.posted.day)
```